# Question about Fourier transform and its itegrability

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $n\geq 1$ an integer. Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be an integrable function. Then its Fourier transform $\widehat{f}$ is defined as
$$\widehat{f}(\xi)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi} dx,$$
where $\cdot$ denotes the scalar product.

The Fourier transform has many properties and there is an extensive theory about it. It is known that if $\widehat{f}$ integrates against polynomials then this implies that $f$ is differentiable up to some order.

My question is the following:

If $f$ is such that $\widehat{f}\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for some $p>1$. Does this tell us anything about $f$ itself? Like for instance if $f$ is bounded, continuous or any other thing?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: By Plancherel's theorem, we have $\hat {f} \in L^2$ if and only if $f \in L^2$.

Comment: This I know, but I wonder what happens if $\widehat{f}\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $p>1$ not only $p=2$, what can we say about $f$? Is it like.. then $f\in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Hausdorff-Young inequality, we know that $\mathcal {F} : L^p \to L^{p'} $ is bounded for $1\leq p \leq 2$. It is easy to see that the same holds for the inverse Fourier transform.

Hence, if $\hat {f} \in L^p $ for some $1\leq p \leq 2$, then $f =\mathcal {F}^{-1}\hat {f } \in L^{p'} $.

Comment: Yes, I thought of Hausdorff-Young inequality :) thanks. But, what happens for $p>2$ though?